# Prevent Default not working, not sure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm supposed to press enter to submit the form

my code doesnt work on this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0fz4hpsw/1/) but it works on this one [FIDDLE2](https://jsfiddle.net/dgw3bw63/2/).
I'm not really sure why and would like to see if anyone knows why. The code is exactly the same

```
var i = 0;
var allowed = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    var input = $('#t_input1').val();
    var ar = $('#t_input1').data('name');
    if (!allowed.test(input)) {
        alert("Name can have only letters and numbers.\n\n Names Already Submitted: " + ar.join(" , "));
        return false;
    } else {
        ar[i] = input;
        alert("Your name was successfully submitted\n\n Names Already Submitted: " + ar.join(" , "));
        i = i + 1;
        return false;
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included `jQuery` in the first fiddle, and that is why `$` can not be resolved or defined error is there.

Second fiddle does includes `jQuery` and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing `$` is not defined. It is means you are not including `jQuery` in your project.
add `jQuery` in your code. [working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0fz4hpsw/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Add 

    $('#form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // Saves from Reloading of page
var input = $('#t_input1').val();
    var ar = $('#t_input1').data('name');
    if(!allowed.test(input)){
        alert("Name can have only letters and numbers.\n\n Names Already Submitted: "+ ar.join(" , "));
        return false;
    }else{
    ar[i]=  input;
            alert("Your name was successfully submitted\n\n Names Already Submitted: "+ ar.join(" , ") );
        i = i+1;
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try the below code
When the input is not matching your regex, then validation will occurs and page will get not submit.
   use preventDefault in  if (!allowed.test(input)) {

```
  $('#form').submit(function (e) {
          var input = $('#t_input1').val();
            var ar = $('#t_input1').data('name');
            if (!allowed.test(input)) {
                alert("Name can have only letters and numbers.\n\n Names Already Submitted: " + ar.join(" , "));
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } else {
                ar[i] = input;
                alert("Your name was successfully submitted\n\n Names Already Submitted: " + ar.join(" , "));
                i = i + 1;
                return false;
            }
        })
```